# Return "zero" for non-existent fields

Tags: php, mongodb

In my mongoDB collection there are some documents which have some **non-existent** fields.

I want these fields to be "zero" when fetching the documents from the collection.

Is there any `method` for that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question a bit to make it more clear and understandable, so you hopefully will get some more answers. If you are not happy with my edits, feel free to undo them.

Answer (score 0):

Because `MongoDB` is `document based DB`, you don't have general table structure like `SQL`. One `BSON` document (mongo document) can have generally different content.

You can make array, which 'll use for base compare.

Comment: MongoDB does not have a schema not because it is document orientated. It does not have one because it is programmed within the core to be schema flexible. Document DBs can accept a base schema just like any DB, but they choose you having to implement it in the application

Comment: To be correct - MongoDB have dynamic schemas, usually the idea to use MongoDB is for situations, where is necessary to have differences. 
To do single document it's good way to do something like this.

Comment: Dynamic and flexible schemas are interchangable, I would challenge you to tell me the difference. I don't know what your last sentence there means

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB non-existant fields, by default, will return `null` and only `null`.

One work around would be to use aggregation:

```
db.c.aggregate([
    {$project: {field: {$ifNull: ['$field', 0]} }}
])
```

but I would not recommend this approach.

Instead I would recommend advancing your application to use a pattern such as Active Record ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern ).

Comment: If I need to do it for specific field, the approach you have suggested is fine. But, the problem is, I don't know which fields are non-existent in some documents. So, I just need to return value zero for all the non-existent fields in those documents.

Comment: @RajuPonnala can't you just code arund this in your application quite easily using a foreach loop over the fields? Add it part of a function when you find your records and you will find it very easy